# Opening Windows console programs in Full Screen Mode

Tags: c, windows, console-application

I am developing a C program that prints out a message. The problem with it is that when I run its `.exe` file, it does not run in fullscreen (until I press alt+enter to force it to full screen). I want the program to run in fullscreen itself when I run it. Is there any way I can do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a programming question, but a Windows one.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is it just a command line program?

Comment: Also, be aware that Windows 7 does not allow you to make full screen console windows at all. Not sure about Vista.

Comment: This question does not belong on SU, why are you voting to move?

Comment: Can there be a way out in Windows?

Comment: @Jon, it may not be a pure 'c' question, but "Can I do this programmatically on Windows?" is certainly a valid question for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call [SetConsoleDisplayMode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to force CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE.  Beware that support for this has been disappearing.  The last machine I owned that could still do this has been gathering dust for quite a while already.  Along with the memory of the loud relay clicking sound, mixed with the high-pitched wail of the flyback transformer in the CRT.